# How to tell whether ObservableCollection is now in CollectionChanged Event?

Tags: observablecollection, syncfusion

In my application, I will need to check whether an `ObservableCollection` is now in `CollectionChanged` Event, and if yes, I will refrain from modifying the collection.

The reason I need to do this is because sometimes my application will fire add or remove event in rapid succession, that even before the previous `CollectionChanged` Event is finished, the next modifying event is already coming. If this happens, then I will get a

> Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event

```
System: System.InvalidOperationException
Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event.
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.CheckReentrancy()
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
   at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.CommitNew()
   at Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.GridAddNewRowController.CommitAddNew(Boolean changeState)
   at Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.GridSelectionController.ProcessSourceCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, CollectionChangedReason reason)
   at Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.GridModel.OnSourceCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.RaiseSourceCollectionChangedEvent(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.SourceNotifyCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
```

In such a situation,it's alright for my application to reject the subsequent modifying event to avoid the crash.

How to actually tell that the previous `CollectionChanged` event is still executing?

Comment: Are you firing events in multiple threads or something? Or is the handler `async` or something? I think it's a better idea to ensure you just don't get two events at once.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen , how to ensure you don't get two events at once ?

Comment: Did you notice the questions in my comment?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen , I did. But I am unsure how is it helpful to my case. For all I know anyone can subscribe to the events . And obviously different threads can fire the collectionchanged event

Comment: After reading the stack trace properly it seems you have a re-entrancy problem instead of two things firing events "in rapid succession" (but if you're using threading you should make very sure you don't touch the UI, or any collections it's observing, from other than the main thread). You probably have some kind of circular dependency between things in your UI, which is going to be next to impossible to debug without debugging the entire program. Because a collection changing causing more items to be added to the collection itself doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, the strange thing is that I can't reproduce the problem. It only occurs once

Comment: Only once ever? Sounds like a nasty race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to reproduce the problem in a small sample-- it turns out that this is a bug in the third party component ( Syncfusion).

I've contacted the support for help